# How does this heavily oxidized copper-to-steel joint work in earthing?

Tags: ground, resistance, grounding

[Wikipedia article on grounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ground_(electricity)&oldid=543629530) features this photo:

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:HomeEarthRodAustralia1.jpg]

Here's a close-up of the joint:

[image: joint close-up]

Clearly the steel rod is heavily oxidized and the copper wire is oxidized. The clamp is coated with something like zinc and is not oxidized.

How does a joint of an oxidized copper wire to the clamp and from the clamp to the oxidized steel rod provide conductivity that is good enough for grounding?

Comment: Which part is the steel? Earthing stakes in my part of the world are either copper, aluminium or some copper alloy (brass?), but not iron (highly corrosion-prone) or steel.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh: The vertical thing looks made of steel to me. In my part of the world steel rods are permitted, but you have to weld steel wire to them.

Comment: I see. It doesn't look the right color, but then this isn't the best of photographs, so it's possible.

Comment: I think this is a bad example of how it should be done. The mushrooming round the top of the rod suggests little care or thought was made when it was installed. There is some discussion around the picture here: http://www.electrical-contractor.net/forums/ubbthreads.php/topics/196224/1.html

Comment: It probably rusted (if it is indeed steel) *after* the clamp was installed. As such, the mating surfaces inside the connection are likely rust-free and making a good connection. It's only the exposed sections that have rusted.

Answer (score 3):

The point of the clamp and crimp connections is to make gas-free joints where the two parts are forced against each other.  People have been making grounding rods for a long time now, and I expect they know what works and what doesn't.  Very likely the electric code also requires certain things be done, again based on history and experience.

Are you sure the rod isn't copper?  The clamp looks like it might be brass, with the wire and rod copper.